# Alfresco workflows and email notifications

Tags: notifications, workflow, alfresco, jbpm

I have written a custom JBPM workflow that for some tasks has to send notifications to the assigned users.

I know how to do it using a custom java action or a simple javascript, but I am trying to use the flag bpm_sendEMailNotifications: if this flag is true, the class org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoAssignment automatically sends the notifications using the utility class org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowNotificationUtils.

For example, the following task in my workflow definition sets the flag to true on the creation of the task.

```
<task-node name="finalReview">
    <task name="mswf:reviewTask">
        <assignment class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoAssignment">
           <pooledactors>#{finalReviewReviewer}</pooledactors>
        </assignment>
        <event type="task-create">
            <script>
                executionContext.setVariable("bpm_sendEMailNotifications", true);
            </script>
        </event>
    </task>
    <transition name="approve" to="endFinalReview"/>
    <transition name="reject" to="endFinalReview"/>
</task-node>
```

Because, when the task is assigned, this flag is true, AlfrescoAssignment tries to send the notifications.

Unfortunately, the transition to this task node fails with the following exception:
"07052361 Accessing task with id='jbpm$200957' is not allowed for user 'atc1'"

atc1 is the user that clicks the transition button and it is not the current user assigned to the task.

The exception is thrown by the class WorkflowNotificationUtils when it tries to get the WorkflowTask (at line 168 for Alfresco enterprise version 4.1.7 that is the first line of the method sendWorkflowAssignedNotificationEMail() ):

```
WorkflowTask workflowTask = services.getWorkflowService().getTaskById(taskId);
```

I verified that the task has been already assigned to a different user, as expected.

I hope that somebody knows what is wrong with this solution. In the mean time, I will try to use this flag with a vanilla workflow to see if it fails as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're still using JBMP? It has been generally recommended to use Activiti for all new workflows in Alfresco for a few years now!

Comment: @Gagravarr: Yes, there is a reason.

Comment: I am confused by your this statement. "atc1 is the user that clicks the transition button and it is not the current user assigned to the task."  . If atc1 is not current user assigned to task how he is able to see transition button?

Comment: @mitpatoliya, you are right, I did not describe it clearly. 
The emails are sent by the action AlfrescoAssignment after the assignment of the task to a different user.
The sequence of events is:
1) atc1 clicks the action "completed" on a previous task
2) This task is ended and a new task is created (the one written above)
3) This task is assigned to the user "legal1" by AlfrescoAssignment
4) AlfrescoAssignment tries to send the email notifications. Because the code is still running on behalf of the authenticated user that is atc1, the access to the new task fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a custom AlfrescoAssigment where the code that sends the email notifications is executed in a runAs:

```
AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new RunAsWork<Void>() {
    public Void doWork() throws Exception {
        //
        // make the assignment
        //
        Boolean sendEMailNotification = (Boolean)finalExecutionContext.getVariable(WorkflowNotificationUtils.PROP_SEND_EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS);
        if (finalAssignedActor != null)
        {
            assignable.setActorId(finalAssignedActor);

            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(sendEMailNotification) == true)
            {
                // Send the notification
                WorkflowNotificationUtils.sendWorkflowAssignedNotificationEMail(
                            services, 
                            JBPMEngine.ENGINE_ID + "$" + finalExecutionContext.getTaskInstance().getId(),
                            finalAssignedActor,
                            false);
            }

        }
        if (finalAssignedPooledActors != null)
        {
            assignable.setPooledActors(finalAssignedPooledActors);

            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(sendEMailNotification) == true)
            {
                // Send the notification
                WorkflowNotificationUtils.sendWorkflowAssignedNotificationEMail(
                        services, 
                        JBPMEngine.ENGINE_ID + "$" + finalExecutionContext.getTaskInstance().getId(),
                        finalAssignedPooledActors,
                        true);
            }
        }         

        return null;
    }

}, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
```